# Multi line bash prompt overlapping

Tags: bash, prompt

I made a bash prompt that is supposed to look like the prompt in kali linux, but when you write a whole line the text restarts on the same line and overlaps with the prompt. My PS1 variable is: `\[\033[38;5;6m\]┌──(\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;4m\]\u@\h\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;6m\])─[\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;4m\]\W\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;6m\]]\[$(tput sgr0)\]\n\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;6m\]└─\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;4m\]\\$\[$(tput sgr0)\]`

non color version: `┌──(\u@\h)─[\W]\n└─\$`

It works without desktop and in some other terminals but not in konsole.

I have a screen recording [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wr3837_JfUs) showing what happens.
Whats wrong with the prompt?

Comment: `My PS1 variable is` where's color? Your `PS1` variable looks way more than that. Please post the output of `printf "%q\n" "$PS1"` or `declare -p PS1`

Comment: @KamilCuk sorry i had the one without color. I updated the post to the colored one